# Same instance with two ids in Spring

Tags: java, spring

Is there any way to use two different ids for referring to the same instance in a Spring context?

What I'm trying to find is a way for aliasing the bean id, for a singleton scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html
**Bean Names** section

> the name attribute may be used. Also note that name accepts an array of Strings. This is in order to allow for specifying multiple names (i.e., aliases) for a single bean.

```
@Bean(name={"b1","b2"}) // bean available as 'b1' and 'b2', but not 'myBean'
public MyBean myBean() {
    // instantiate and configure MyBean obj
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `@Bean` annotation (Spring 3.0+) with its `name` value.

> The name of this bean, or if plural, aliases for this bean. If left unspecified the name of the bean is the name of the annotated method. If specified, the method name is ignored.

```
public @interface Bean {
    String[] name() default {};
    ...
}
```

For example, your bean of `C` class will be available as `a` or `b` (BUT not `c`) in a Spring context.

```
public @Bean(name = {"a", "b"}) C getInstance() { ... }
```